# Add a tag to Stack Overflow for Google Refine?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags

A couple of days ago I answered [Parse JSON in Google Refine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10304238/parse-json-in-google-refine-solved).

The question sat for hours unanswered, which I consider rare on Stack Overflow. I found out about the question because I happen to know the questioner in real life. Looking back, I can't help but think none of the tags on that question (`google`, `json`, `parsing`) are particularly appropriate. But I couldn't think of any *better* tags to add.

Is it time for [google-refine](/questions/tagged/google-refine)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Done.](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/10304238/5)

This tag is enough to stand on it's own as it's a tool in the same way [visual-studio](/questions/tagged/visual-studio) is. nor is it ambiguous or vague.